# Uploading files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**A Problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination**

**Unable to upload the file in codeigniter using their upload class**, upload directory is also exist, 
below is a code

```
$config = array(
                'upload_path' => './upload_dir/users_docs/',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|png|jpeg',
                'max_size' => 0,
                'max_width' => 0,
                'max_height' => 0,
                'file_name' => $this->currTime,
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!empty($_FILES['company_logo']['name']) && !$this->upload->do_upload('company_logo')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', $error['error']);
            redirect('home');
        }
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
```

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: provide the full error log

Comment: I m getting this error, A Problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination

Comment: Folder permissions? Is Codeigniter allowed to write to that folder?

Comment: @kerbholz folder is in the project root, while I also  changed the folder permission mode to 777 before uploading the file, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in the 'file_name' => $this->currTime, the format of time was not correct, **Apostrophe where coming in the filename var**, I just changed it to something else, now it's working, Thank you